# Horizontal Step View in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement a horizontal StepView with a custom Steps Icon and title.

I am using this library https://github.com/shuhart/StepView
[Horizontal step view with number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwLfy.png)

I'm expecting this type of work without using Viewpager but I will use the next and back buttons to move forward and backward.
[Horizontal step view with icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqi5w.png)

I need to replace each step number with a different icon. Can anyone guide me on how to do it?

Comment: https://github.com/params-ing/StepViewAndroid

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can't do that with this implementation; the numbers are part of the view that isn't changeable; if you really want to do that, you have to fork this library and provide a different implementation in the `StepView.java` in which you swap the numbers with icons of your own.